# Can't call child component method from parent component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native component `<Parent>` that contains a component `<Child>`, and I want to be able to call one of Child's methods in Parent. After reading a bunch of other posts, this is what I have:

**Child.js**

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  method1() {
    console.log("success");
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View/>
    )
  }
}
```

**Parent**

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.child.method1()}
        />
        <Child
          onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error "_this2.child.method1 is not a function."

Other things I've tried are using `refInput` instead of `onRef`, and doing `ref => {this.child = ref}` instead of `ref => (this.child = ref)`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: any solution yet

Answer (score 6):

You can create a ref using `React.createRef` in the constructor and assign it to the Child component instance using `ref` prop

Post that you can access the child using `this.child.current`

Sample code:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  myMethod() {
    console.log("myMethod called");
  }

  render() {
    return <Text>This is child</Text>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Image
            accessibilityLabel="React logo"
            source={{ uri: logoUri }}
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={styles.logo}
          />
          <Text style={styles.title}>React Native for Web</Text>
        </View>
        <Child ref={this.child} />
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            this.child.current.myMethod();
          }}
          title="Example button(Click to trigger Child)"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-mountain-20let?file=/src/App.js:2793-3629)**

IF your child component is connected with connect from redux, you can still access the childRef by setting the withRef option to true in connect

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(Child);
```

If you are using v6 or above of redux, set the forwardRef property instead of withRef

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { forwardRef: true })(Child);
```

Once you do that in the parent you will be able to access the cchild ref with

```
this.child.current.getWrappedInstance()
```

Comment: Its not working, its say this.child.current.myMethod is not a function

Comment: Please check the demo. It does work. Also define the attribute as a ref on Child

Comment: Can you have a demo on mobile,  I already told its working in react web platform

Comment: I just check your code in expo snack, its working there, but I dont know why its not working on my IOS device.

Comment: Use a separate function for handlePress as shown in expo

Comment: I think the problem is with my react-native version, bcz i just create expo snack of my code, and its working in expo. but its not working on my simulator.

Comment: @SagarChavada you can try to upgrade your version of react, react-native and react-dom

Comment: I just create new project with latest configuration, but its still not working, right now my react version is ==>. "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",  What is yours?

Comment: make sure react and react-dom both have the same version in your code

Comment: @SagarChavada Ohh you were wrapping your child component with connect. Do you want me to change my answer for it?

Comment: @SagarChavada Updated my answer to make it work with connect too

Comment: do you mean this.child.current.getWrappedInstance().methodName() right?

Comment: @SagarChavada yes, in order to execute the method

Comment: Thank you, You'r a lifesaver

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is by passing a function down to the child, that the child can pass a function to. For example:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this.childFunc()}
/>
<Child addMethod={func => this.childFunc = func}/>
```

Then just call the `props.addFunc(this.method1)` from inside the child. Just make sure your `this` is the one you want.

More importantly though, you should ask yourself *why* you need to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ref** to call child method

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.refs.child.method1()}//<---------
        />
        <Child
          ref="child"//<-------
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You are suggesting the usage of a legacy API ["Legacy API: String Refs"](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) *"We advise against it because string refs have [some issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/8333#issuecomment-271648615), are considered legacy, and **are likely to be removed in one of the future releases**."*

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem.

@Shubham khatri's answer will definitely work, It will only not work with redux.

if your child class is wrap with `connect`

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Athletes);
```

It will not work in this case so make sure you use it normal way, if you want to call child method from parent class.